# how to pass a not like operator in a sqlalchemy ORM query

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, negation

I've got a query:

```
MyModel.query.filter(Mymodel.name.contains('a_string'))
```

I need to do the same query but with the negation (a **not like** operator) but didn't find any operator matching my need in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators).

Is there any way to do it without using the sql part of SQLAlchemy???

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Just negate the filter:

```
MyModel.query.filter(sqlalchemy.not_(Mymodel.name.contains('a_string')))
```

Comment: Or `MyModel.query.filter(~Mymodel.name.contains('a_string'))`

Comment: Right answer give Vroo. 'Contains' not have same functional as LIKE operator.
If you want compatibility with sql code you need use this variant with '~'

Comment: [Link to docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=not_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_)

Answer (score 14):

There is now a `notlike()` method. Couldn't find it in the docs but it exists!

```
MyModel.query.filter(Mymodel.name.notlike('%a_string%'))
```

Comment: Here it is in the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.notlike